# php database to javascript chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts

How to replace my javascript datapoints to my mysql database?
My array x and y ??? i have trouble in plotting my mysql database...

ex.

```
array("x" =>(HERE), "y" =>HERE),
   by database $row['year'];



<?php

 $dataPoints = array(
  array("x" => 946665000000, "y" => 40),
  array("x" => 978287400000, "y" => 20),
  array("x" => 1009823400000, "y" => 100),
  array("x" => 1041359400000, "y" => 300),
  array("x" => 1072895400000, "y" => 500),
  array("x" => 1104517800000, "y" => 500),
  array("x" => 1136053800000, "y" => 400),
  array("x" => 1167589800000, "y" => 400),

 );

?>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div> 
 <script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  title:{
    text: "Number of Enrollees by Year"
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "Students in numbers",
    valueFormatString: "#",
    suffix: "",
    prefix: ""
  },
  data: [{
    type: "spline",
    markerSize: 5,
    xValueFormatString: "YYYY",
    yValueFormatString: "##0. Enrolees",
    xValueType: "dateTime",
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
  }]
});

chart1.render();

}
</script>
```

> Its just a template from chartjs.com
>
> Please help me guys form database php to javascript...

Comment: Done thankyou for clarificaition

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. You can [edit] the question and make it clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as :

```
array_walk($dataPoints, function (&$dp, $index) use($show) {
$dp['y'] = $show['table_data'][$index]['y'];
})
```

I hope to help you.

Comment: 'array("x" => 946665000000, "y" => 40);'   

                                                                               
I want to Change the value of "y" from database $show['table_data'];

Comment: Oh, OK; if you want to change only 'y' values from $dataPoints you must be do it :
array_walk($dataPoints, function(&$dp, $index) use($show) {$dp['y'] = $show['table_data'][$index]['y'];});